# Matrix that maximizes/minimizes the trace

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $B$ be a non-singular square matrix of order $n$.

**Q**:

1) How to show that an orthogonal matrix $U$ that maximizes $f(U):=tr(UB)$ satisfies 
$$U=(\sqrt{B^T\cdot B})^{-1}B^T=B^T\sqrt{BB^T}^{-1}.$$

2) Let $G$ and $H$ be symmetric positive definite matrices of order $n$.

How to find a matrix $L$, that minimizes
$$h(L):=tr((I-L)G(I-L)^T),$$
subject to $LGL^T=H$.

PS: I tried to use the variantional method, but it did not work.

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/754301/maximizing-the-trace) for part 1.

Answer (score 0):

(1) is a rather standard exercise that can be solved easily by applying singular value decomposition to $B$.

For (2), the trace in question is $-2\operatorname{tr}(LG)$ plus a constant term. So you are asked to *maximise* $\operatorname{tr}(LG)$ subject to the constraint $LGL^T=H$.

Let $B=G^{1/2}LG^{1/2}$ and $A=G^{1/2}HG^{1/2}$. Then, equivalently, you are asked to maximise $\operatorname{tr}(B)$ subject to $BB^T=A$.

Let $B=PU$ be a polar decomposition. Then $BB^T=A$ implies that $P=A^{1/2}$. In turn, you are asked to maximise $\operatorname{tr}(A^{1/2}U)$ over all orthogonal matrices $U$. Now you may apply the result of (1).

Comment: Sorry, I am not smart enough, could you explain more details for the (1).

Comment: @DLIN Sorry, I haven't time to elaborate on that.